# How to make the saturation longer?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a map and I wanted to make the saturation slower because we all know that Minecraft Bedrock Edition's saturation is rigged and depletes so quickly.

So, any ideas to make it slower?

Command or mods for MINECRAFT PE

or scripts

Comment: but hey I am not saying to turn it off completely just slower like java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

effect <player: target> <effect: Effect> [seconds: int] [amplifier: int] [hideParticles: Boolean]

i guess you can try it (above is some effect u can add saturation effect i guess?

link: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/effect )

i hope it helps u! :D

btw i replied/answered your Give query.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).